# After how many cycles does this pattern repeats ? Is there any value of n>3 for which it does not repeat at all?

Tags: proof-writing, pattern-recognition

I have **N** numbers in an array **A**. The numbers are either **0** or **1** and given that **A[1]=0** as well as **A[N]=0**.

In every operation the array changes as follows:

- If a cell has two adjacent values that are both equal, then the value becomes 1.
- Otherwise it becomes 0.
- **First** and **last** cells always remain **0**.

Example:

[0,0,1,0,1,0]

[0,0,1,1,1,0]

[0,0,0,1,0,0]

[0,1,0,1,0,0]

[0,1,1,1,0,0]

[0,0,1,0,0,0]

[0,0,1,0,1,0]

Is is possible to derive a general formula **f(N)** for the number of iteration after which the pattern will repeat itself.

Comment: Your question and examples are very unclear. You say A[n - 1] = 0 but in many of your example arrays you have a value of 1. You specify A[0] = 0 only then talk about 2 adjecent values. Do we need to know A[1]? I cannot make any sense of your examples, if we are supposed to go from one to the next or if they are separate.

Comment: Reminds of $1$-dimentional case of [Conway's_Game_of_Life](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conway%27s_Game_of_Life). In $\mathbb{Z}_2$ we can write $f_{n,k}=1-(f_{n-1,k-1}-f_{n-1,k+1})$ and this results to a matrix equation in $\mathbb{Z}_2$: $\quad f_n=Af_{n-1}$ we need to find minimal $n>0$ for $A^n=I$ over $\mathbb{Z}_2$. @RajnishKumar

Comment: i have corrected all the ambiguity @Paul

Comment: It always ends in a cycle, but that might not include the first position.  It seems that, if you start with $A[2]=1$ and everything else zero, it cycles back to that position unless $N=4k+1$ for some $k$.  The periods seem irregular to me.